# Get the uploaded photo from Graph API

Tags: facebook, graph, upload, photo, access-token

I developing a process to upload a photo to a users account with the graph api. While I am successful with being able upload the photo. I unable to retrieve the same said photo that was uploaded just 2 seconds ago. Using a user's access_token I get "false". Using an Application's access token i get

> "A user access token is required to request this resource"

How are you suppose to retrieve the url of the photo that you just uploaded with the graph api

Comment: I have been trying to access the uploaded photo but I keep getting false. Why would I get false on trying to retrieve the photo that was just uploaded? It was successfully posted to the user's albums...I'm using the FB js to get it. The photo was uploaded since yesterday...IF the token had expired wouldn't the error message read token expired? WHY CAN'T I GET IT...it is driving me crazy?

Comment: the following is the code I use to retrieve the photo using JS `code` var f = l('logo');
 FB.api('/' + f, function(response) {
     var r = response;
      return response.picture;
    }); `code`

Where l('logo') is the id number that was returned from uploading a photo to a user's album via the Graph API both r and response return false. 

What does false mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I had to update my SDKs

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the photo, it should return an ID.  Use that ID to access it.  Also, you may have to wait until that photo has finished processing.  Try the call again in a few minutes after the photo has been uploaded.

Comment: I am aware of the ID returned...it was being able to retrieve it was the problem. I guess I was calling the endpoint too soon after it was uploaded. I'll try it...I think this may have been the problem

Comment: Sorry but no dice...the photo was uploaded to the user's album but I still can't get it from the graph...

Comment: I have been trying to access the uploaded photo but I keep getting false. Why would I get false on trying to retrieve the photo that was just uploaded? It was successfully posted to the user's albums...I'm using the FB js to get it. The photo was uploaded since yesterday...IF the token had expired wouldn't the error message read token expired? WHY CAN'T I GET IT...it is driving me crazy?

Answer (score 0):

`$data = $facebook->api('/'. $ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $args);`

`$data['id']` is the id of the image you just uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if sometimes you can't access the photo without getting an access token with the `"user_photos"` permission.  Sometimes, as in, for some users you don't need it, and for some you do.  Most excellent.

EDIT: actually, this only seemed to work in the graph API explorer and not the iOS app.  At least they're consistent.